# Ascii name of value

Tags: c++, c, ascii

Is there a way to get the name of the value of ascii.

for example

0x08 or just 8 is the backspace

can I get the name "Backspace" in c or c++?

Comment: type `man ascii`，press enter

Comment: Or, if you don't have `man`, you could google "ASCII" and find something like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/ASCII_Code_Chart-Quick_ref_card.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.  Easily worked around, though.

If your ASCII code is < 32, here's table of standard ASCII control character abbreviations you can use:

```
char *ascii_cc[] = {
  "NUL", "SOH", "STX", "ETX", "EOT", "ENQ", "ACK", "BEL", 
  "BS",  "HT",  "LF",  "VT",  "FF",  "CR",  "SO",  "SI",
  "DLE", "DC1", "DC2", "DC3", "DC4", "NAK", "SYN", "ETB",
  "CAN", "EM",  "SUB", "ESC", "FS",  "GS",  "RS",  "US" };
```

Then just index into that array of strings by the value of the `char` you're interested in.  e.g.

```
char c = 8; /* backspace */
printf("ASCII control code = %s\n", ascii_cc[c]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only 128 of them (the last 128 differ, depending on what code page do you use), why don't you create a const array? If you narrow down your data to non-printable characters, the number of items drops to 32.

You can find the complete list on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Here are first 32 values:

```
Dec    Abbr    Name
0      NUL     Null character
1      SOH     Start of Header
2      STX     Start of Text
3      ETX     End of Text
4      EOT     End of Transmission
5      ENQ     Enquiry
6      ACK     Acknowledgment
7      BEL     Bell
8      BS      Backspace[d][e]
9      HT      Horizontal Tab[f]
10     LF      Line feed
11     VT      Vertical Tab
12     FF      Form feed
13     CR      Carriage return[g]
14     SO      Shift Out
15     SI      Shift In
16     DLE     Data Link Escape
17     DC1     Device Control 1 (oft. XON)
18     DC2     Device Control 2
19     DC3     Device Control 3 (oft. XOFF)
20     DC4     Device Control 4
21     NAK     Negative Acknowledgement
22     SYN     Synchronous idle
23     ETB     End of Transmission Block
24     CAN     Cancel
25     EM      End of Medium
26     SUB     Substitute
27     ESC     Escape[i]
28     FS      File Separator
29     GS      Group Separator
30     RS      Record Separator
31     US      Unit Separator
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in the standard and I am not aware of a third-party library capable to do that. Your best option is to create a table with the mappings on your own. You will only have to create a few special mappings as most of the characters are called the way they are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`man ASCII` can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cmd = popen("man ASCII", "r");
    char *key = "010";
    char result[128];

    while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd) != NULL)
        if (strstr(result, key))
            printf("key %s: %s", key, result);
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```