# Prettyprint ascii values for keystrokes in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ascii, keystroke

When my program's user hits an unused key, even a key that lacks a viewable glyph, I want to report something like "Warning: ignoring keystroke Ctrl+W".  That's kinder  than "ignoring keystroke whose decimal value is 23; go google that yourself, doofus."

So, does C or C++ have *any* vaguely standard way to convert ints to strings, something like this?

```
65 -> "A"
141 -> "a"
32 -> "SPACE"
3 -> "CTRL+c"
26 -> "Ctrl+Z"
```

This many decades after the decline of EBCDIC, copypasting a table such as "man ascii" is just too embarrassing ( [Ascii name of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785619/ascii-name-of-value) ).

Comment: Your program is reading these keystrokes in a non-standard manner. Use that system's conversions.

Comment: It's reading keystrokes with a GLUT callback.  Blame GLUT.

Comment: 1-26 is just Ctrl+A - Ctrl-Z, that's straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic problem.

First we need to sort out ASCII values vs. keystrokes.  ASCII is a character encoding with values 0 to 127.  Keystrokes "codes" vary but usually map to ASCII when available (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> makes ASCII code 97) and to other codes or actions for the *other* keys like <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>right arrow</kbd>, etc.  Typically a keyboard has more than 256 possible keystroke combinations.  Further, some keyboard interfaces may directly generate Unicode which has over a million codes.

As typically `char` is 8 bits (256 codes) and usually codes 0 to 127 as ASCII and the remainder very system dependent.  The `isprint()` or `isgraph()` may be used to sort out the " viewable glyph" requirement.  After that one may need to roll you own code.

```
// Sample handler
int keystroke = OP_GetKeystroke();  // fictitious system dependent function
if (OP_IsChar(keystroke)) {
  char ch = keystroke;
  if (isascii(ch)) {
    if (isprint(ch)) {
      printf("%c", ch);
    }
    else if (ch < ' ') {
      printf("<Ctrl-%c>", ch+'@');
    }
    else {
      printf("<DEL>");
    }
  }
  else { 
    printf("<\x%02X>", ch & 0xFF);  // char codes outside ASCII range 
  }
}
else {
  printf("<Key: %X>", keystroke);  // keystroke outside char range 
  }
```

---

`isprint()` true for ASCII codes 32 to 126.
`isgraph()` true for the same codes as `isprint()` expect code 32 (space).
This answer is problematic in non-ASCII environments.

Comment: Except for brace mismatches and testing for 32, this catches anything that the GLUT keyboard callback can read from a U.S. 101-key keyboard.  Good enough!

Comment: @Camille Goudeseune Fixed braces.  `if (isgrpah(ch))` and test for `space` are in order.  Sounds like you know well how to adapt it though.   BTW: there is not a standard C `isascii()` function.  This whole problem becomes challenging should we want high portability especially attempting to work in a non-ASCII C environment and/or keyboard.

Comment: Yes, greatly generalizing this is as tricky as building a bridge strong enough to carry an infinitely heavy truck... something that works "most of the time" is good enough here.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted 'A' which is 65 in ASCII table cast int to (char):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int temp = 65;
   cout << (char)temp << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if OP wants "space" ?

Comment: As the other answer stated this could possibly be used with a lookup, although at work so didn't read the question thoroughly.